# Insert view from file in Revit API

Tags: revit, revit-api

Is there a way to insert views from a file using the Revit API?  I'm using the Revit 2013 API.  It would need to be the same as the functionality below.  Here is a [similar question](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-Revit-API/Importing-specific-views-from-a-RVT-file/m-p/3252498/highlight/true#M2436) on the Autodesk Revit API Forums.

[image: Insert Views from File]

Comment: Reading your question brought me to recall that AC can be controlled by taking over the command line like I show in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388918/select-whole-drawing-in-autocad-without-prompting-user/14394657#14394657). Not sure if your searches brought you to [this](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/12/driving-revit-from-outside.html) but it sounds hackishly delicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update for Revit 2014 API**

This is now possible with the Revit 2014 API.  If you download the *Revit 2014 SDK* there is a sample project *DuplicateViews* which has a class called `DuplicateViewUtils` that contains 2 functions, `DuplicateSchedules` and `DuplicateDraftingViews` which allows you to copy those 2 types of views from one document to another.  The key component is the `ElementTransformUtils.CopyElements` function which allows you to select a *from* and a *to* document for your copy.

---

**Response for Revit 2013 API**

I got a [response](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-Revit-API/Importing-specific-views-from-a-RVT-file/m-p/3756589#M3524) from one of the Revit API gurus, Arnošt Löbel, and he said that this is not currently possible with the Revit 2013 API but that it has high priority for future releases.  Only time will tell if this feature gets included...